# freebsd-update IDS reports wrong SHA256 on every single file on my system

Tags: freebsd

How come `freebsd-update` says following on every single file on my file system?

```
# freebsd-update IDS > freebsd-update.IDS
# tail -1 freebsd-update.IDS 
/var/db/mergemaster.mtree has SHA256 hash 5c63e12b1be6753032106eced68e9deefd4da2f7ce2469f09e7535e73db98824, but should have SHA256 hash 98f9c24fb623045918b8f24aa427d268b1aad78585231b8a29599a72a81af147.
# wc -l freebsd-update.IDS 
   26665 freebsd-update.IDS
#
```

Comment: . . . because the SHA256 hash of every single file on your system doesn't match what `freebsd-update IDS` thinks they should be? Did you rebuild your system from source at some point, or do something else which may have perturbed it?

Comment: i used freebsd-update to update my freebsd, I did not build it from source